# Change in hash rate fraction of mining pools

Tags: mining-pools

There are pages that show how the cumulative hash rate of network changes over time however, I wasn't able to find any that shows how hash rate fraction of pools change over time. Is there a page that traces this metric?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this page for the current share and keep a record?
[Bitcoin Hashrate Distribution](https://blockchain.info/pools)